# Placing content in one of two columns depending on the lower view height

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In a vue app, I would like to place content from an array in one of two columns, the column that has the lowest view height. So that if there is "one" and "two" in the left one, then "three" would get put into the column2, and then four would get put into column2 as well.

Right now, getHeight is only running once, after the v-for has rendered everything.

TEMPLATE

```
<div>
  <div class="container flex">
  <div class="column" ref="column1">

    <div v-for="e in ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']" 
:key="e">
      <div v-if="getHeight">
        <div>{{e}}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column" ref="column2">

    <div v-for="e in ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']" 
:key="e">
      <div v-if="!getHeight">
        <div>{{e}}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

SCRIPT

```
 const getHeight = computed(() => {
 
  if (!column1.value && !column2.value) {
    return false;
  }
  
  if (column1.value.offsetHeight <= 
 column2.value.offsetHeight) {
  
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
 };
```

CSS

```
.container {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.column {
  flex: 1;
 flex: 1 1 auto;
 overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Comment: this question looks very familiar - have you asked it before?